# How would I replicate a file hierarchy from template?

Tags: c#, file, resources

I need to restore a certain file hierarchy in a folder, after it gets deleted (yeah, don't ask).

For now I imagine it as a simple application that gets run by Windows Task Scheduler. While there are some ways to achieve that effect, I wanted to create a simple **single exe**.

So I put my structure into my project, and set all files Build Action to "Embedded resource". I can sort of access them through `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()` and `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(name)`, however I don't see any simple way to preserve hierarchy like that.

While I'm solving a real problem, the question is more academic in nature - I don't need anything convoluted, like parsing resource name to determine what hierarchy it resulted from. My file structure actually is just 4 files in two folders, if push comes to shove I can just write everything out manually.

I'm sure there should be a simple way to just say "Hey, here's how those files should be arranged, repeat". Maybe resources are a wrong mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, you can't. Because resource names are identifiers, some characters are replaced during the build and you can't store empty folders either You can however build a Zip file from the structure embed that single file and extract it when needed - with one single call if you want. The framework [has built-in zip support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files). Please note however that the `ZipFile` can't be accessed concurrently only sequentially as there is only a single inner state.